# \includegraphics takes the wrong image if no extension is specified

Tags: graphics, external-files, include

The following code incorrectly displays the image with the letter `B` in the header of the first page, even though I included the image with the letter `A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{xxx}{\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}}
\pagestyle{xxx}
\begin{document}
1\vspace{26cm}\par2\par\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: BAB]

(The sample images are downloaded from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a.pdf and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-b.pdf)

However, if I add `.pdf` to the `\includegraphics`, I get the expected output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{xxx}{\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.pdf}}}
\pagestyle{xxx}
\begin{document}
1\vspace{26cm}\par2\par\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: AAB]

I find this very confusing.  Does somebody have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: I assume your body content was intended to make two pages: the first with just a single character, and a second with a single character and an image. If so, replacing it with `1\clearpage 2` followed by whitespace and the `\includegraphics` command seems to clear things up. Don't know the root cause of your problem, though.

Comment: I suspect that when TeX is deciding to make a page break it goes up to the inclusion of the image and then the code for finding the image when no extension is given is evaluated at a time that causes the image loader to point at the wrong resource. It happens also when `xelatex` is used, so it shouldn't be `pdftex.def`.

Comment: This same thing just happened to me and indeed it is very confusing. The trick of explicitly specifying the image extension fixed this for me, so thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Interesting.

Not seen that before, I'd work around it as follows but we should probably make it not do that (not sure if it's `graphics` or `pdftex.def` at present)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr}
\newbox\zzz
\sbox\zzz{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\fancypagestyle{xxx}{\fancyhead[C]{\usebox\zzz}}
\setlength\headheight{67pt}
\pagestyle{xxx}
\begin{document}
1\vspace{26cm}\par2\par\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It happens also with `xelatex` and `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, so it doesn't seem to be `pdftex.def`.